# Programmatically log in user not working correctly

Tags: 7, users

Here's what I am doing:

```
global $user;

if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
  $user = user_load(31);
  user_login_finalize();
  echo $user->uid;
}
```

When a user is not logged in - we have to log in him as user with id 31. I have placed this code at top of `page.tpl.php`.

I am noticing some strange behavior. If I visit the homepage (http://ggames.kz/), at the top I can see the id 31, that's correct. However, if I visit the user page (http://ggames.kz/user), it shows that I am not logged in. If I refresh the browser or visit another pages, I am logged in. I can't figure out why it won't authenticate user from the first page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template files are not the proper place for your code, since at this level the headers are (probably) already sent. That's why the session cannot be saved on the client browser.

You'd better implement [`hook_init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) in a custom module

```
function YOURMODULE_init() {
  if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    global $user;
    $user = user_load(31);
    user_login_finalize();
  }
}
```

> If I refresh the browser or visit another pages, I am logged in.

You are seeing the correct user ID on your debug output, just because you are printing the user id which you have loaded just 2 lines before. It doesn't mean that the user is successfully logged in.

Comment: call to undefined function user_is_logged_in() now when i am using hook_boot()

Comment: Used hook_init() instead and it did the job :) thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The correct code to impersonate another user is the following.

```
global $user;
drupal_save_session(FALSE);
$user = user_load(31);
```

As said in [Safely Impersonating Another User](https://www.drupal.org/node/218104), this code is also safer, since the session will not be saved.

If you need to change back the user after doing something, then the code should be the following one.

```
global $user;
$original_user = $user;
$old_state = drupal_save_session();
drupal_save_session(FALSE);
$user = user_load(31);

// Your code here

$user = $original_user;
drupal_save_session($old_state);
```

As side note, changing the user account for the current user should not be something done in a template file. This type of code is expected to be executed in a module, in one of the hooks Drupal makes available, such as `hook_init()`.